# Sequelize. How to find with many parameters

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a postgre database with table `User (firstname, lastname, age, profilePicture, gender, intention)`, and I have an object filter:

```
filter = {
        firstname: String
        lastname: String,
        withPhoto: Boolean,
        minAge: Integer,
        maxAge: Integer,
        isMale: Boolean,
        intention: String //sex/friendship/communication
    }
```

What is the best way to select users by this filter?

Comment: `UserModel.find({where: filter});` http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where

Comment: @blex, but it woudn`t understand minAge, maxAge fields

Answer (score 1):

If all your filters correspond to table fields, you could simply use [`where`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where):

```
UserModel.find({ where: filter });
```

But since you have a `minAge` and `maxAge`, you can add a `between` [operator](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators):

```
UserModel.find({
  where: {
    firstname: filter.firstname
    lastname: filter.lastname,
    withPhoto: filter.withPhoto,
    isMale: filter.isMale,
    intention: filter.intention,
    age: {
      [Sequelize.Op.between]: [filter.minAge, filter.maxAge]
    }
  }
});
```